# Apache Solr: Conditional block

Tags: indexing, solr, hbase, bigdata

I am reading columns from HBase and indexing it in Solr using morphines file. Some field values will be in either English or German. Is there a way to specify the type of the field as "text_english_german" and inside the definition of "text_english_german" can we do an condition check to see if it is English or German and use the language specific Stemmer filter factory for indexing and querying the data?

Thanks,
Kishore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a slightly different approach, you could define two fields:

- text_en
- text_de

Each of them would have a language-specific text analysis configured. Then, you can use the language autodetection UpdateRequestProcessor [1]. There a lot of parameters where you can tune the behaviour of such component.

---

[1] https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection
[2] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Detecting+Languages+During+Indexing

Comment: Thanks Andrea for quick reply, I will check and let you know.